# How do I capture all exceptions of Spring/Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I built my Spring boot 2.x application using this demo:

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/
```

The problem I'm having is that when there's an exception in Spring/Spring boot, it is printed to standard output. I don't want that. I want to capture them and do other processing such as logging them. I can capture the exceptions of my code but I can't capture the exceptions of Spring/Spring boot. Therefore, how do I capture all exceptions of Spring/Spring Boot 2.x so I can handle them? Is there an easy way to do this, like a generic exception catcher? Can someone show me some code?

My Code:

**1. Example.java**

```
   package example;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
   import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Example extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
      
     }
  
   }
```

**2. ExampleController.java**

```
   package example;


   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
   import org.springframework.ui.Model;
   import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
   import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


   @Controller
   public class ExampleController {
  

     @GetMapping ("/example")
     public ModelAndView example()
     {
        MyData data= new MyData();
        data.setName("Example");
        data.setVersion("1.0");
    
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("page");
        model.addObject("page", data);
     
       return model;
     }
            
   }
```

**3. GeneralExceptionHandler.java**

```
   package example;

   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

   @ControllerAdvice
   class GeneralExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleException() {
      
      System.out.println("Exception handler");
      
    }
   }
```

**4. MyData.java**

```
   package example;

   import lombok.Data;

   @Data
   public class MyData {
  
     private String name;
     private String version;
   }
```

**5. page.jsp**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

  <html> 

   <form:form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" 
    modelAttribute="page">
    <form:label id="name" class="control-label" path="name" for="name">
    ${page.name}</form:label>
    <!-- Error introduced on purpose to force exception. "version123" should be just "version" -->
    <form:label id="version" class="control-label" path="version" for="version">
    ${page.version123}</form:label>
   </form:form>
      
  </html>
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler

Comment: please provide us what you've done, so that we can help you

Comment: page.jsp file: <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html> 

   <form:form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" 
    modelAttribute="page">
    <form:label id="name" class="control-label" path="name" for="name">
    ${page.name}</form:label>
    <!-- Error introduced on purpose to force exception. "version123" should be just "version" -->
    <form:label id="version" class="control-label" path="version" for="version">
    ${page.version123}</form:label>
  </form:form>
      
</html>

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi Not sure why your answer got deleted. Did you see the code that I posted? I tried your suggested solution but it did not worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JBNizet Did you see the code that I posted? I tried the solution but it did not work.

Comment: I think it is absolutely appalling that there is no answer to this question. I am new to Java and have been fighting this all day without success. It seems that there is genuinely no way to do this. You can catch exceptions thrown by the controllers, but there is no way to catch exceptions that are thrown prior to calling the controller or after it returns, making it impossible to write professional quality applications with spring/boot. How exactly is this better than the tools we were using 20 years ago?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@ExceptionHandler` annotation to catch a specific Exception, to do that you can simply annotate a method inside your controller with `@ExceptionHandler` and provide it with a specific exception, example :

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void handleException(){
 // do some thing here
}
```

The limite of this way of doing is that it will handle only exceptions thrown by the `@RequestMapping` where the `@ExceptionHandler` is declared. To avoid this limitation you can use a **Controller advice** which allows you to use exactly the same exception handling techniques but apply them across the whole application, example using controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GeneralExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void handleException() {
        // Do some thing here
    }
}
```

*hint : if you want to catch all checked exceptions you can use @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)*

Comment: page.jsp Code: <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html> 
   <form:form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" 
    modelAttribute="page">
    <form:label id="name" class="control-label" path="name" for="name">
    ${page.name}</form:label>
    <!-- Error introduced on purpose to force exception. "version123" should be just "version" -->
    <form:label id="version" class="control-label" path="version" for="version">
    ${page.version123}</form:label>
  </form:form>
</html>

Comment: Solution doesn't work. See the code that I posted. It still throws Spring boot exceptions to standard output. Unfortunatelly, the page.jsp code got cut by Stackoverflow but get the idea. – code4u 1 hour ago

Answer (score 1):

You can use AOP with pointcut on all public method in Controller.
I use BaseController as base class for all my Controllers.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/application")
public class ApllicationController extends ApiController {
   //class body with method
}
```

Then add AOP handling all exceptions throw from public methods in Controller.

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class AOP_ApiController {

    @Pointcut("execution (public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("execution (* api.ApiController+.*(..))")//here package and class name as base class
    private void methodOfApiController() {}


    @AfterThrowing(value="methodOfApiController() && anyPublicMethod()", throwing="exception")
    public void afterThrowingExceptionFromApiController(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) throws Exception {
        ApiController controller = getController(joinPoint);
        String methodName=getMethodName(joinPoint);
        logException(exception, controller, methodName);
        throw exception;
    }

    private ApiController getController(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        return (ApiController) joinPoint.getTarget();
    }

    private String getMethodName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        return joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    }

    private void logException(Exception ufeException, ApiController controller, String methodName) {
        //log exception as you want
    }
}
```