# How do I catch all exceptions in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-jms

I want to be sure my team always log exceptions thrown. Is there any way to catch all exceptions (regardless of entry point) in a Spring Boot application?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198071/how-do-i-capture-all-exceptions-of-spring-spring-boot-2-x) of using `@ControllerAdvice` (and `@RestControllerAdvice`) is the wrong answer for this question as it only catches exceptions for code started by `@Controller` components. Code can be started in many different ways, for example `@JmsListener` annotated methods run when receiving a message from a queue. Exceptions thrown in code started by a JmsListener is not caught by handlers in ControllerAdvice.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot integration modules usually come with a configurable error handler mechanism. and the user will able to configure this handler for application purposes. for example, the JMS listener container [factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/config/DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.html) can be configured by giving it a custom error handler and you can catch all errors in the listener as you specify.

If you are considering a more general configuration around the application, you should use an application [instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming)) solution for this and follow the entire application. like a [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) or other similar tools. This approach is more likely at an infrastructure level and managed by an outside application as an agent.

Comment: Nice. Instrumenting seems to be the way to go for general catch-all. Jaeger docs mentions [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/) which our log aggregator supports.